# How can I create a application to login into another web site with no API

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, automation

I need to create an application, which logs into a web site (username/pwd) with my credentials but this web site has no API or authentication protocol (its not been updated since 1998, but I need data from it continuously).

Is there anyway to do this? Preferably in Python but can use any language or tools.

I have been searching Google but most people have APIs to work with.

Comment: May be a bit overkill, but you could use selenium to access the pages.  Once logged in you should be able to parse the DOM to extract the data you are looking for.
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

Comment: I need the application to do the login for me. In essence I just want to be able to launch this application feed it some song names and have the application handle the authentication portion

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can use the Python Selenium bindings to get this set up fairly painlessly.

Another option is the Mechanize family of tools (Python's is http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

If you want a less heavyweight solution (that doesn't require a hefty web browser instance like Selenium or any third-party packages) you can most likely use the curl command-line client to authenticate to the app and send your requests, then put the curl commands into a shell or Python script.

You can get a head start on developing a curl solution using the Chrome dev tools:

- With the dev tools open, bring up the Network tab
- Select the "Preserve log" checkbox
- Manually navigate to your web app in the browser and log in
- Perform any other actions you want to automate
- You should now have a list of requests in the Network tab
- Scan through the requests and determine which are important (e.g., GETs for images can be ignored)
- For each request you want to include in your script, right click the item and click ""Copy as cURL" option to get the curl equivalent of the request in your clipboard.
- The string Chrome places in your clipboard will be very verbose; you can likely remove several bits and still have a working request, if you want to clean it up.
- Parameterize the requests as necessary, and you should have the beginnings of a working shell script for your task.